# Integrating Hadoop and HDF5

Tags: hadoop, hdf5

I am working on a project which needs the use of HDF5 and hadoop. Thanks for Stack overflow,which directed me to SciHadoop ! I did a little search on net and got to know that SciHadoop supports NetCDF. 
Has sciHadoop expanded its support to HDF5 ?
I would be very glad if someone directs me towards getting HDF5 and Hadoop together.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Glad to see your post here. I am the author of SciMATE, and our group has been developing a lot of products which support various operations over NetCDF/HDF5 datasets. Could you please tell me what kind of functionality you need?

Answer (score 1):

Although SciHadoop folks have been working hard towards adding HDF5 support, still some more work is required. See this [thread](http://www.mail-archive.com/hdf-forum@hdfgroup.org/msg04105.html).

As an alternative you might find SciMATE helpful. Although I haven't tried it personally but reading their paper gives an impression that it's worth giving it a try. You can find the paper [here](http://www.cse.ohio-state.edu/~agrawal/allpapers/ccgrid2012_yw.pdf).

HTH